# char array c ((SIGSEGV) (core dumped))

Tags: c++, linux, string, ubuntu

I have problem in c++ in eclipse ubuntu. My code is:

```
string Bi1 [N];
for(int j=1; j<=N;j++){
    char *cstr2 = new char[Bi2[j].length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr2, Bi2[j].c_str());
    delete [] cstr2;
}
```

After start the program crashed: ... (SIGSEGV) (core dumped)...

In windows visual studio work fine.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Your unlucky visual studio worked. Bi2[j] is likely not valid when j==N, and thus the length function is free to crash horribly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ arrays start at 0 and end at N-1

```
for(int j=0; j<N;j++){
```

You may need to make a similar adjustment elsewhere in your code.

Comment: +1 Assuming `Bi2` and `Bi1` have similar indexing (and I assume they do, thus the premature up-vote), I'm guessing this same problem is replicated wherever `Bi2` is *populated*.

Comment: @WhozCraig To be honest I hadn't even noticed that they were different arrays.

Comment: Ssshhh you're not supposed to say that. =P

Comment: I think we have to make some reasonable assumptions when faced with potential absurdity. I would assume Bi2 is the same size as Bi2, but tis good someone pointed it out explicitly.